# Тестирование шаблонного класса с помощью Unit-тестов

Tags: c++, visual-studio, юнит-тесты

Всем доброго времени суток! Опишу вкратце: у меня есть шаблонный класс, методы которого нужно протестировать с помощью Unit-тестов. Можно ли как-то обойти прописывание тестов для каждого типа данных (а мне необходимо проверить стандартные типы данных + самодельные структуры) или еще нет такой возможности?

Пишу в Visual Studio 2017, для юнит-тестов использую CppUnitTestFramework.

Comment: Мне тут в англоязычном сегменте попалось вот такое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441677/c-unit-test-testing-using-template-test-class), а конкретно второй ответ. Но я не знаю, насколько это правильно.

Comment: Принятый ответ по Вашей ссылке делает всё правильно, этого ответа должно быть достаточно для старта.

Comment: Нет, обойти это никак не получится. Для выполнения кода шаблонов их необходимо истанцировать для каждого конкретного типа.

Comment: Какой фреймворк вы используете для юнит-тестов? В Catch2, например, есть встроенные возможности для этого

Comment: @cppquestions, CppUnitTestFramework в MS VS 2017

Comment: Зачем вы откатили правку? Метка `шаблоны` явно не имеет отношения к вопросу. Также добавьте информацию про фреймворк в сам вопрос

Comment: @cppquestions, так речь идет о шаблонных классах. Или я что-то не понимаю? Просто я впервые использую как шаблонные классы, так и юнит-тесты. Мне казалось, что эта метка уместна, но хорошо, отредактирую вопрос